# Button enableWhen TableView selectedItem is not empty

Tags: tornadofx

TableView selectedItem is bind to *ViewModel* and i want to button be disabled when selectedItem is *null* and enabled otherwise.

```
class MainView: View("TheSubberKt") {
  override val root = Form()
  val model = MainViewModel()

  init {
    with(root) {
      fieldset {
        field("Media:") {
          textfield(model.mediaPath)
          button("...")
        }
      }
      tableview(subs) {
        // ...
        bindSelected(model.selectedSubtitle)
      }
      hbox {
        button("Hash Search")
        button("Download Selected") {
          // what to do here?
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I imagine that i have to create a `OvservableValue<Boolean>` and then pass to `enableWhen` but, how to do that?

Is it possible to map a property `onChange` to a custom observable? (just another idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observable values have a function that will return an `BooleanBinding` when they don't contain a value, and since you've already bound the selected item to `model.selectedSubtitle`, you can simply add the following expression inside of the button builder:

`enableWhen(model.selectedSubtitle.isNotNull)`

If you didn't bind the selected item of the TableView to a property accessible in the view, you could store a reference to the table directly and bind to state in the table's selection model:

`enableWhen(table.selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().isNotNull)`

On another note, you can clean up your syntax by getting rid of the `init` block and declare the root node directly with a builder:

```
override val root = tableview(subs) {
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps :)